# Fantasy series in which an evil overlord creates a wall of darkness

Tags: story-identification, books

A fantasy series of books from before 2000, in which an evil overlord created a wall of cloudy darkness (mists?) which slowly engulfed the world.

He imprisoned a girl - the main character I suppose - in a tower, standard torturing by hunger, cold. She communicated with the other characters with the help of some birds or insects through the only window.

There was a location called Cairngorm (which pretty much muddled all my searches). Some rats (controlled by someone?) chew the playing bones of orcs in the caves below causing a meek one to always win - generating a distraction.

There might have been a sword involved in defeating the overlord. I distinctly remember there being a god or powerful character named Vili (as in Odin's brother, but I don't recall any other Norse connections).

Comment: There's a Cairngorn (with an n) Keep in the Dragonlance novels

Comment: Doesn't seem to be it. There's no wall of darkness in those. But it might have been indeed Cairngorn, not with M.

Comment: The wall of darkness reminds me of The Sword of Shannara; to enter the Warlock Lord's northern kingdom you have to pass through an area that is dark and spooky.  And darkness is taking over the world as his forces spread.  I don't remember Cairngorm or Cairngorn, but there is a "Callahorn", which is somewhat similar.  But no Vili that I remember.  And the part with the imprisoned girl does not fit.

Comment: There are also mountains called Cairngorn in the [Schooled in Magic](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20927280-schooled-in-magic) series by Christopher Nuttall.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is one of the books of the [*Runesword*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?16591) (1990-1992) series, by various authors.  The mixed bag of adventurers, Elizabeth the witch, Endril the elf, Hathor the vegetarian troll and Caltus the warrior are recruited by the god Vili to retrieve the titular swords in order to fight The Dark Lord of Mistwall.

> Bith, then Hathor, then Cal in the rear, joined him on the flinty crest. They drew a sharp breath at the strange sight. On this cloudless day in this cloudless clime, far to the west. they beheld the common enemy of all the speaking races.
>
> The thing was a line of cloud, or fog: a storm cloud come to ground. The bank was tall, very tall, reaching almost to where normal clouds would fly. The clouds that formed this bank were not still. They roiled and boiled and fluttered and rippled up and down its sheer face. Color flitted through the cloud like a dirty rainbow—grey where it touched the ground, a tinge of purple here, a jot of red there, green where the sun hit it along the top, with orange streaks. But none of the colors were beautiful. They were the colors of bruises on skin, of mold on vegetables, of dried blood or vomit, of sun-bleached bones and things long dead.
>
> But the most curious feature of the cloud was its straight-ness. True, the wall of cloud billowed out here or receded there, but its front edge was as cleanly cut as if with a knife.
>
> The tremendous wall ran from north by east to south by west, and it stretched from horizon to horizon and obviously beyond. It was all the eye could see in looking west, a giant sea wave poised to come crashing down on all civilization.
>
> Cal said aloud to no one in particular, "So that's it. eh?"
>
> "Aye," replied Endril. "The Mistwall."

The party visit a Castle Cairngorm in the first book, and the name crops up in later books.  But despite my quote above (from the first book), I think it must be the second book [*Skryling's Blade*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?13101), by Rose Estes and Tom Wham, you remember since in that book Elizabeth and Endril are captured.

Comment: That's the one! I've been racking my brains for months now. Thank you.